# Populate fileds in list items with user profile data

Tags: list, user-profile-service

I have example list with column/fields: Name, Department, ID.
In Active Directory i have add value to extensionAttribute9 in user account.
In Central Administration-> User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Properties i have add field ID and get sync with AD. Now i see this value in User Profile Page.
I need this value from ID record in my list ID column.
How can I do this? Can I achive this?

Comment: Yes please have a look at this documentation: https://www.simego.com/blog/synchronise-active-directory-users-with-sharepoint-list

Comment: Thank you for youre replay. But this is third party tool. I need to achieve what i describe with standard sharepoint functionality.